# Move from PCM PIC16 Microcontroller to PCH PIC18

Tags: c, microcontroller, i2c

I have  written a C code for PCM PIC 16 Microcontroller. I have now replaced the board with a PCH PIC 18. I am having issues configuring the new board. Here is an excerpt of my code where I am getting the errors.

```
#include "i2c_custom.h"


const int getIIC_period_us(){
    return (1000/IIC_CLOCK_KHz);
}

#ifdef USE_IIC_CCS_FUNCTION
int i2c_custom_read(int ack) {return i2c_read(ack);}
void i2c_custom_stop() {i2c_stop();}
void i2c_custom_start() {i2c_start();}
int i2c_custom_write(int8 data) {return i2c_write(data);}

#else

int i2c_custom_read(int ack) {
    int data=0;
    for(int i=7;i>=-1;i--)
        {
        if(i>=0){
            i2c_custom_delay_us(IIC_period_4);
            data |= (input(hw_IIC_SDA)<<i);
        }else{
            if(ack)     output_low(hw_IIC_SDA);
            else        output_high(hw_IIC_SDA);
            i2c_custom_delay_us(IIC_period_4);
        }
        i2c_custom_delay_us(IIC_period_4);
        output_high(hw_IIC_SCL);
        i2c_custom_delay_us(IIC_period_2);
        output_low(hw_IIC_SCL);
        }
        return data;
}


void i2c_custom_stop() {
        if(input_state(hw_IIC_SDA) || input_state(hw_IIC_SCL)){
            output_low(hw_IIC_SCL);
            output_low(hw_IIC_SDA);
            i2c_custom_delay_us(IIC_period_4);
        }
        output_high(hw_IIC_SCL);
        i2c_custom_delay_us(IIC_period_4);
        output_high(hw_IIC_SDA);
        i2c_custom_delay_us(IIC_period_4);
}


void i2c_custom_start() {
        if(!input_state(hw_IIC_SDA) || !input_state(hw_IIC_SCL)){
            output_high(hw_IIC_SDA);
            output_high(hw_IIC_SCL);
            i2c_custom_delay_us(IIC_period_4);
        }
        output_low(hw_IIC_SDA);
        i2c_custom_delay_us(IIC_period_4);
        output_low(hw_IIC_SCL);
}


int i2c_custom_write(int8 data) {
        int ack=0;
        for(int i=7;i>=-1;i--)
        {
            if(i>=0){
                if((data&(0x01<<i)) ==0)    output_low(hw_IIC_SDA);
                else                    output_high(hw_IIC_SDA);
                i2c_custom_delay_us(IIC_period_4);
            }else{
                i2c_custom_delay_us(IIC_period_4);
                ack= input(hw_IIC_SDA);
            }
            i2c_custom_delay_us(IIC_period_4);
            output_high(hw_IIC_SCL);
            i2c_custom_delay_us(IIC_period_2);
            output_low(hw_IIC_SCL);
        }
        return ack;
}

void i2c_custom_delay_us(int delay){
    for(int i=0;i<delay;i++)
        delay_us(1);
}

#endif
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Error#51  A numeric expression must appear here  :: i2c_read() not supported when using MASTER mode and HW I2C on this device, see i2c_transfer():

Error#112  Function used but not defined:  :: i2c_stop() not supported when using HW I2C on this device, see i2c_transfer():

Error#112  Function used but not defined:  :: i2c_start() not supported when using HW I2C on this device, see i2c_transfer():

Error#51  A numeric expression must appear here  :: i2c_write() not supported when using MASTER mode and HW I2C on this device, see i2c_transfer():
```

I am not sure if I have to replace i2c_start(),i2c_stop(),i2c_read(), i2c_write() with i2c_transfer(). But I am not sure how to use i2c_transfer().

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Which compiler? You are missing some library functions. Have a look at the MCC.

Comment: CCS C Compilerr

Answer (score 1):

I've been using PIC18F and been implementing i2c on our project. If you are using a CCS C compiler, you may use the built in i2c library using *#use i2c* directive.

You may read and write thru i2c_read() and i2c_write() function.

to trigger a read command you may do the following code:

```
i2c_start(); // initiate a start command
i2c_write(address << 1 | 1); // left shift bit of the device address and declare LSB to '1' to trigger read bit.
data = i2c_read(0); // read a single byte of data transferred and send NACK
i2c_stop(); // stop command
delay_ms(50);
```

to trigger a write command you may do the following code:

```
 i2c_start(); // initiate a start command
 i2c_write(address << 1 | 0); // left shift device address and declare LSB to '0' to trigger write bit.
 i2c_write(data); // write a single byte data
 i2c_stop(); // stop command
 delay_ms(50);
```

note that this functions only reads and writes a single byte. if you want to read or write a string of data you must use while loops.